# Setup prometheus alerts for different environments

Tags: prometheus

I would like to setup more or less the same alert for prod and dev( for example: high cpu usage)
I.e. i woud like to see [prod] my alert and [dev] my alert.
I can define separate alert for prod  and separate alert for dev. it will work ok. But will be good to have something like template of alert and change title and instance only for prod and dev.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Often you can do with one alert:

1. Use `or` statements:

```yaml
groups:
- name: alerts
  rules:
  - alert: MyAlert
    expr: my_metric{env="dev"} < 10 or my_metric{env="prod"} < 1
```

2. Define thresholds as metrics:

```yaml
groups:
- name: thresholds
  rules:
  # This creates an additional metric which you can use
  # in alert expression.
  - record: my_metric:alert_threshold
    expr: 1
    labels:
      env: prod
  - record: my_metric:alert_threshold
    expr: 10
    labels:
      env: dev

- name: alerts
  rules:
  - alert: MyAlert
    expr: my_metric < my_metric:alert_threshold
```

Label and annotation values can be templated using `golang` template syntax ([some examples](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/template_examples/)). But, as far as I know, there is nothing (except for third-party tools) to template `for` value. For example, I use `Ansible` along with `jinja2` templates to render some rules in a loop and deploy `Prometheus` configuration.